# If $\{x,y,z\}\subset[-1,1]$ and $x+y+z=0$ so $\sum\limits_{cyc}\sqrt{1+x+\frac{y^2}{6}}\leq3$

Tags: inequality, contest-math

Let $\{x,y,z\}\subset[-1,1]$ such that $x+y+z=0$. Prove that:
$$\sqrt{1+x+\frac{y^2}{6}}+\sqrt{1+y+\frac{z^2}{6}}+\sqrt{1+z+\frac{x^2}{6}}\leq3$$
I tried C-S, but without success.

Comment: Nice question. Is this from a competition? For me, the most natural thing to do is to apply Jensen's inequality to the square root function, but unfortunately this only shows that the left hand side is less than approx 3.24. ie not quite strong enough.

Comment: @ S. Catterall It's one of my old unsolved problems.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg do you happen to remember where the question is from?  Even what level (high school/college) the question comes from?  If it's college it seems like some ugly work with derivatives/gradients might let you show that $x=y=z=0$ is a maximum on the domain.

Comment: @ Mathily I found this problem here:http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h284076 I think it from some test or some contest for school students.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg, suppose that I able to show that the inequality under the condition $x+y+z=0$ has the form $x^2+y^2+z^2 \leq 0$. Can one argue that since  $x^2+y^2+z^2 \leq 0$ iff $x=y=z=0$ which holds under the condition, completes the proof? My guess is, that it isn't.

Comment: No, you can not. I think it's very strange to assume that $x^2+y^2+z^2\leq0$. Why not $x=y=z=0$? For these numbers the inequality is true and we still need to prove the starting inequality.

Answer (score 4):

Let $Z = \{\,(x,y,z) \in [-1,1]^3 \mid x+y+z=0\,\}$.

Let $f \colon Z \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be the function given by
$$f(x,y,z) = \sqrt{1+x+\frac{y^2}{6}} + \sqrt{1+y+\frac{z^2}{6}} + \sqrt{1+z+\frac{x^2}{6}}.$$

Let $g \colon \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be the function given by
\begin{align*}
  g(x,y) =\ &x^4+2 x^3 y-2 x^3+3 x^2 y^2+9 x^2 y+4 x^2
  \\ &+2 x y^3+15 x y^2+4 x y+y^4+2 y^3+4 y^2.
\end{align*}

**Lemma 1.** If $(x,y,z) \in Z$ and $g(x,y) \geq 0$, then $f(x,y,z) \leq 3$.

*Proof.*
Let $(x,y,z) \in Z$ such that $g(x,y) \geq 0$. Define $\lambda_1 = \frac{x+2}{6}$, $\lambda_2 = \frac{y+2}{6}$ and $\lambda_3 = \frac{z+2}{6}$.
We have $\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\lambda_3 \geq 0$ and $\lambda_1+\lambda_2+\lambda_3=1$. Since $\alpha \mapsto \sqrt{\alpha}$ is concave, we have by Jensen's inequality:
\begin{align*}
  f(x,y,z) &= \sqrt{1+x+\frac{y^2}{6}} + \sqrt{1+y+\frac{z^2}{6}} + \sqrt{1+z+\frac{x^2}{6}}
  \\ &= 
    \lambda_1 \sqrt{\frac{6 x+y^2+6}{6 \lambda_1 ^2}} 
  + \lambda_2 \sqrt{\frac{6 y+z^2+6}{6 \lambda_2 ^2}}
  + \lambda_3 \sqrt{\frac{6 z+x^2+6}{6 \lambda_3 ^2}}
  \\ &\leq
  \sqrt{  \lambda_1 \frac{6 x+y^2+6}{6 \lambda_1 ^2} 
        + \lambda_2 \frac{6 y+z^2+6}{6 \lambda_2 ^2} 
        + \lambda_3 \frac{6 z+x^2+6}{6 \lambda_3 ^2}}
  \\ &=
  \sqrt{  \frac{6 x+y^2+6}{x+2}
        + \frac{6 y+z^2+6}{y+2}
        + \frac{6 z+x^2+6}{z+2}}.
\end{align*}
We rewrite the fractions inside the square root to have the same denominator and then replace $z$ with $-x-y$:
\begin{align*}
  &(9 - f(x,y,z)^2) (x+2) (y+2) (z+2) \\&\geq \left(9-\frac{6 x+y^2+6}{x+2}
        - \frac{6 y+z^2+6}{y+2}
        - \frac{6 z+x^2+6}{z+2}\right) (x+2) (y+2) (z+2)
    \\&= g(x,y) \geq 0.
\end{align*}
$$\tag*{$\Box$}$$

Let $\widetilde{Z} = \{\,(x,y,z) \in Z \mid z \leq x \land z \leq y\,\}$.

**Lemma 2.** If $(x,y,z) \in \widetilde{Z}$, then $-3 x^2+6 x+4 y \geq 0$.

*Proof.*
Let $(x,y,z) \in \widetilde{Z}$. If $x \geq 0$, then we have:
\begin{align*}
  -3 x^2+6 x+4 y &= 3x(1+(1-x))+4 y
  \\&\geq 3x+4y
  \\&\geq 2x+4y
  \\&\geq 2x+2y+2z = 0.
\end{align*}
If $x < 0$, then we have:
\begin{align*}
  -3 x^2+6 x+4 y &= -3x^2 -2x + 4y + 8x
  \\&\geq  -3x^2 -2x + 4y + 4x + 4z
  \\&= -x(3x+2)
  \\&\geq -2x(2x+1)
  \\&\geq -2x(x+z+1)
  \\&= -2x(-y+1) \geq 0.
\end{align*}
$$\tag*{$\Box$}$$

Let $\widetilde{g} \colon \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be the function given by
\begin{align*}
\widetilde{g}(x,y) &= g(x,y)-y^2(-3 x^2+6 x+4 y)-2 (1-x) (1-y) (x+y)^2
\\ &= x^4 + 2 x^2 y^2 + y^4 + 15 x^2 y + 15 x y^2 + 2 x^2 + 2 y^2.
\end{align*}

**Corollary 2.1.** If $(x,y,z) \in \widetilde{Z}$ and $\widetilde{g}(x,y) \geq 0$, then $g(x,y) \geq 0$ and by Lemma 1 we have $f(x,y,z) \leq 3$.

Let $\hat{Z} = \{\,(x,y,z) \in \widetilde{Z} \mid x > 0\,\}$.

Let $\hat{g} \colon \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be the function given by
\begin{align*}
\hat{g}(x,y) &= \frac{1}{x}\left(\widetilde{g}(x,y)-(1 - x) (2 y^2 + y^4) - x y^4\right)
\\ &= x^3+2 x y^2+15 x y+2 x+17 y^2
\\ &= (17+2x) y^2 + 15 x y + x^3 + 2 x.
\end{align*}

**Lemma 3.** If $\hat{g}(x,y) \geq 0$ for all $(x,y,z) \in \hat{Z}$, then $f(x,y,z) \leq 3$ for all $(x,y,z) \in Z$.

*Proof.*
Let $(x,y,z) \in Z$.

Then there exists $(\widetilde{x},\widetilde{y},\widetilde{z}) \in  \{\,(x,y,z),(y,z,x),(z,x,y)\,\} \cap \widetilde{Z}$.

If $\widetilde{x} = \widetilde{y} = \widetilde{z} = 0$, then $f(x,y,z) = f(0,0,0) = 3$.

If $\widetilde{z} < 0$, then there exists $(\hat{x},\hat{y},\hat{z}) \in  \{\,(\widetilde{x},\widetilde{y},\widetilde{z}), (\widetilde{y},\widetilde{x},\widetilde{z})\,\} \cap \hat{Z}$.

Since $\hat{g}(\hat{x},\hat{y}) \geq 0$ and $\hat{x} > 0$, we have $\widetilde{g}(\hat{x},\hat{y}) \geq 0$ by the definition of $\hat{g}$. Hence $\widetilde{g}(\widetilde{x},\widetilde{y}) = \widetilde{g}(\hat{x},\hat{y}) \geq 0$.
By Corollary 2.1 we have $ f(\widetilde{x},\widetilde{y},\widetilde{z}) \leq 3$, hence $f(x,y,z) = f(\widetilde{x},\widetilde{y},\widetilde{z}) \leq 3$.
$$\tag*{$\Box$}$$

**Lemma 4.** If $(x,y,z) \in \hat{Z}$, then $\hat{g}(x,y) > 0$.

*Proof.*
Let $(x,y,z) \in \hat{Z}$. The function $\mu \mapsto \hat{g}(x,\mu)$ is quadratic with $17+2x > 0, 15x > 0$, therefore it has a minimum point at $\mu = -\frac{15x}{34+4x}$.

Let $h \colon [0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be the function given by
\begin{align*}
h(\lambda) 
    &= \frac{4 (17 + 2 \lambda)}{\lambda} \cdot \hat{g}(\lambda, -\frac{15\lambda}{34+4\lambda})
    \\&= 8 \lambda^3+68 \lambda^2-209 \lambda+136.
\end{align*} 
We have $h'(\lambda) = 24 \lambda^2+136 \lambda-209 < 0$ for all $\lambda \in [0,1]$. Therefore, $h$ is monotonically decreasing. Since $h(1) = 3$, $h$ is positive.

We have:
\begin{align*}
\hat{g}(x,y)
    &\geq \hat{g}(x, -\frac{15x}{34+4x})
    \\&= \frac{x}{4 (17 + 2 x)} \cdot h(x)
    \\&> 0.
\end{align*}
$$\tag*{$\Box$}$$

**Corollary 4.1.** By Lemma 3 and Lemma 4, we have that $f(x,y,z) \leq 3$ for all $(x,y,z) \in Z$.

Answer (score 0):

@cafaxo gave a nice method to eliminate the root signs. Let $\lambda_1 = \frac{2+x}{6}, \ \lambda_2 = \frac{2+y}{6}, \ \lambda_3 = \frac{2+z}{6}.$
It holds that $\lambda_1, \lambda_2, \lambda_3 > 0; \ \lambda_1 + \lambda_2 + \lambda_3 = 1.$ Note that $t\mapsto \sqrt{t}, \ t \ge 0$ is concave.
@cafaxo obtained
\begin{align}
&\sqrt{1 + x + \frac{y^2}{6}} + \sqrt{1 + y + \frac{z^2}{6}} + \sqrt{1 + z + \frac{x^2}{6}}\\
=\ & \lambda_1 \sqrt{\frac{1 + x + \frac{y^2}{6}}{\lambda_1^2}}
+ \lambda_2 \sqrt{\frac{1 + y + \frac{z^2}{6}}{\lambda_2^2}} + \lambda_3 \sqrt{\frac{1 + z + \frac{x^2}{6}}{\lambda_3^2}}\\
\le \ &
\sqrt{\frac{1 + x + \frac{y^2}{6}}{\lambda_1} + \frac{1 + y + \frac{z^2}{6}}{\lambda_2} + \frac{1 + z + \frac{x^2}{6}}{\lambda_3}}\\
= \ & \sqrt{\frac{6 + 6x + y^2}{2+x} + \frac{6 + 6y + z^2}{2+y} + \frac{6 + 6z + x^2}{2+z}}.
\end{align}
It suffices to prove that
$$\frac{6 + 6x + y^2}{2+x} + \frac{6 + 6y + z^2}{2+y} + \frac{6 + 6z + x^2}{2+z} \le 9$$
or (noting that $z = -x-y$)
\begin{align}
&x^4+2 x^3 y+3 x^2 y^2+2 x y^3+y^4-2 x^3+9 x^2 y+15 x y^2+2 y^3\\
&\quad +4 x^2+4 x y+4 y^2 \ge 0 \tag{1}
\end{align}
for $x, y\in [-1, 1]; \ -1\le x + y \le 1.$

**My solution**

Let me give a different method to prove (1).

With computer, here is a SOS (Sum of Squares) solution:

(1) is true since (note: $A_1, A_2, A_3, A_4$ are all positive semidefinite)
\begin{align}
&x^4+2 x^3 y+3 x^2 y^2+2 x y^3+y^4-2 x^3+9 x^2 y+15 x y^2+2 y^3+4 x^2+4 x y+4 y^2\\
=\ & \frac{1}{60}\Big[u^TA_1u + (1-x)u^TA_2u + (1-y)u^TA_3u + (x+y+1)u^TA_4u\Big]
\end{align}
where
$$u = \left(\begin{array}{c}  x\\  y\\ x^2\\  xy\\ y^2 \end{array}\right), $$
$$
A_1 = \left(\begin{array}{ccccc} 140 & 80 & -30 & 165 & 120\\ 80 & 150 & 55 & 230 & 51\\ -30 & 55 & 60 & 60 & -40\\ 165 & 230 & 60 & 380 & 120\\ 120 & 51 & -40 & 120 & 108 \end{array}\right), \quad A_2 = \left(\begin{array}{ccccc} 80 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 40\\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\ 40 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 20 \end{array}\right),
$$
$$A_3 = \left(\begin{array}{ccccc} 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 10 & 0 & 0 & 14\\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 14 & 0 & 0 & 20 \end{array}\right),
\quad A_4 = \left(\begin{array}{ccccc} 20 & 40 & 0 & 0 & -20\\ 40 & 80 & 0 & 0 & -40\\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\ -20 & -40 & 0 & 0 & 20 \end{array}\right).$$